# Generate mesh surface from protein structure

Tags: proteins, structural-biology, protein-structure, 3d-structure, xray-crystallography

What tools are most widely used for generating a mesh surface of a protein from an x-ray crystallographic structure (from the PDB)? Pros and cons would be appreciated.

I'd prefer the output to be a watertight triangle mesh of the protein surface.
Also, I'd like the tool to be scriptable (i.e. no need to open a GUI).

So far, I've been playing with [MSMS](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/packages/MSMS/) and [EDTSurf](http://zhanglab.ccmb.med.umich.edu/EDTSurf/). But I was wondering what was standard in research, as well as if there was anything in the standard bioinformatics libraries.

Comment: Do you want to visualize the protein surface or the electron density map? (PyMOL can do both.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyMOL](https://pymol.org/2) and [Chimera](http://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimera) can do that, and both can be script-driven. The [PyMOL wiki](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page) is full of examples, and probably already has some how-to that would get you started. Chimera also has [a complete documentation](http://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimera/docindex.html).